# Conditional proofs and subderivations

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

I've been working on logical proofs since quite some time, but recently I came up with a question about conditional proofs, which at first seemed really trivial, nevertheless I still haven't found a convincing answer to it. Let's work with the following example: Let $P \rightarrow Q$ and $Q \rightarrow R$ and prove $P \rightarrow R$:

(1) $P \rightarrow Q$ (P)

(2) $Q \rightarrow R$ (P)

(3) ---| $P$ (A)

(4) ---| $Q$ (MP: 1, 3)

(5) ---| $R$ (MP: 2, 4)

(6) $P \rightarrow R$ (CP: 5)

My question is: why does the derivation of $P \rightarrow R$ specifically retract the subderivation 3-5, while the other formulas inside it ($Q$ and $R$) do not? I can't figure out any circunstance that makes the derivation of $P \rightarrow R$ in any aspect different in comparison to the previous ones. That $P \rightarrow R$ is the goal of the proof cannot be the answer, since in some other examples with different goals, the retraction still occurs in the same place, although the proof continues. As far as I can see, what makes $P \rightarrow R$ ends the subderivation is the fact that we previously know that the formula directly derives from the primary premises of the proof and does not depend on the hypothetical assumption $P$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are rules of inference that allow us to "discharge" assumptions, like Conditional proof (aka: [Conditional Introduction](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4)) and others that do not, like e.g. [Conjunction Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction).

When we use one of the rules that allow the discharging, we may decide to discharge or not one of the assumptions that are "active".

In the specific case, in step (3) we start a sub-proof with the assumption $P$. Then we use Modus Ponens (aka: Conditional Elimination) that does not discharge any assumption.

When we use CP in step (6) we are allowed to discharge the assumption, closing the sub-proof.

The same for e.g. [Indirect Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction#Principle): we assume $\lnot P$, derive a contradiction and conclude with $P$, discharging the assumption.

Comment: I suppose we can only close the subderivation, if we find a formula that directly derives from the primary premises in the main derivation chain. My question is exactly this one: how CP ensures me that $P \rightarrow R$ derives from the original premises, if I could, for example, derive other formulas in the subderivation (like $Q \rightarrow P$) that do not follow from the primary assumptions?

Comment: @TylerD007 - you can derive $Q \to P$, because you are under assumption $P$ and you have derived $Q$ and you can re-iterate assumption $P$ and then apply CP to derive $Q \to P$. **BUT** you have not discharged assumption $P$ and thus your sub-proof amounts to $P \vdash Q \to P$ that is *valid* (check with truth table)... but it is not what you are searching for.

Comment: I see... hence, the assumption $P$ can only be discharged, if we derive a formula with the structure $P \rightarrow X$, where $X$ stands for a formula inside the subproof. Is that so?

Comment: @TylerD007 - yes and no. There are also other rules (few) that allow for discharging... But having said that, yes, you discharge it when you can (using the appropriate rule) and you close the sub-proof.

Comment: Which other rules allow the discharging?

Comment: @TylerD007 - I'll refer to [Natural deduction](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4): Negation Introduction, Disjunction Elimination, Double Negation Elimination, Existential Elimination.